# Keyboard short in Gnome-paint

Tags: keyboard

In gnome-paint program, any shortcut key is there to make eraser big? I have tried Crtl+ + key as in Ms Paint. But it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The GUI of `gnome-paint` is a `ui` file

```
/usr/share/gnome-paint/ui/gnome_paint.ui
```

All available shortcuts are

```
<accelerator key="n" signal="activate" modifiers="GDK_CONTROL_MASK"/>
<accelerator key="o" signal="activate" modifiers="GDK_CONTROL_MASK"/>
<accelerator key="s" signal="activate" modifiers="GDK_CONTROL_MASK"/>
<accelerator key="s" signal="activate" modifiers="GDK_SHIFT_MASK | GDK_CONTROL_MASK"/>
<accelerator key="q" signal="activate" modifiers="GDK_CONTROL_MASK"/>
<accelerator key="z" signal="activate" modifiers="GDK_CONTROL_MASK"/>
<accelerator key="z" signal="activate" modifiers="GDK_SHIFT_MASK | GDK_CONTROL_MASK"/>
<accelerator key="x" signal="activate" modifiers="GDK_CONTROL_MASK"/>
<accelerator key="c" signal="activate" modifiers="GDK_CONTROL_MASK"/>
<accelerator key="v" signal="activate" modifiers="GDK_CONTROL_MASK"/>
<accelerator key="Delete" signal="activate"/>
```

- `GDK_CONTROL_MASK` means <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
- `GDK_SHIFT_MASK` means <kbd>Shift</kbd>
- `GDK_SHIFT_MASK | GDK_CONTROL_MASK` means <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>

Therefore you have e.g.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>  and so on.

---

Other shortcuts I could not find in the source code, e.g. via

```
apt-get source gnome-paint
grep -r 'keyval' gnome-paint-0.4.0/src
```